# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest')

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am running my app and I face this issue. currently I am implement Flutter Sign-in with google.
the error is attached below. kindly look into it.

1)
ERROR when I run the App is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
  - Type 'CheckManifest' property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'.

    Reason: A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
      2. Annotate with @InputDirectory for directories.
      3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

or

[click on the link to open image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANzyc.png)

2. 

my pubspec.yaml file include:

```
 version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

3. 

my app level gradle build

```
   defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.fyp1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: Perhaps check your `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'`, make sure it is on version 4.x.x instead of 3.x.x